# How do you record 0 (zero) results in a Sumo Logic log search?

Tags: logging, sumologic

I'm trying to produce a dashboard for quick identification of system issues using Sumo Logic.

We currently log specific strings in our system when certain code paths are executed. For example:

```py
def get_alerts():
    log.info(event=LogEvents.GET_ALERTS_STARTED)
 ...
```

In the case of potentially unwanted system behaviour we log inside blocks of business logic:

```py
...

elif is_last_import_is_after_start_of_new_import_interval:
        log.warn(
            event=LogEvents.POTENTIAL_IMPORT_DUPLICATION,
            reason="last import occured after the start of the new import interval",
        )

...
```

The problem is that when there are no potentially unwanted system behaviours (such as no instances of `POTENTIAL_IMPORT_DUPLICATION`), the log line is never printed, so my query fails.

The query I'm using is as follows:

```
_sourceCategory=infosec/edr/logs/prod
| json "message" as msg
| json field=msg "message"
| count(message) by message
| if (message matches "POTENTIAL_IMPORT_DUPLICATION", _count, 0)
```

The final line here (`if (message matches "POTENTIAL_IMPORT_DUPLICATION", _count, 0)`), is my latest attempt to output 0 to the results table if no log messages match that string. Instead, the results table just fails to include the string:

[image: Sumo query results showing no logs when searched for string is not found]

Can anyone help me with getting an additional row in this table that would potentially read:

| message | _count |
| --- | --- |
| POTENTIAL_IMPORT_DUPLICATION | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [| fillmissing](https://help.sumologic.com/docs/search/search-query-language/search-operators/fillmissing/) operator.

(Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic)